# Duda básica sobre peticiones al servidor

Tags: http, servidor, http-post

Amigos tengo 3 archivos en javascript. cada uno tiene una  función

1. Para el menu.
2. Para la barra social.
3. Fancybox.

Son funciones cortas y no crean conflicto entre si. para mejorar las peticiones al servidor (que no son muchas) ¿Qué recomendación me sugieren?

1. Tener cada archivo por separado.
2. Unirlos todos en un archivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu proyecto es pequeño dudo que afecte mucho el que tengas varios archivos o uno solo.

Si tu proyecto fuese grande sí sería una mejor opción el *minificar* los archivos.

Pero si aún así quieres minificar tus archivos para mejorar y/o practicar te recomiendo la siguiente liga https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS